# XNA 4 - How to not spawn asteroids in same row?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have asteroids spawning in my game with a timer on when they spawn and I want them to spawn one at a time. My problem is they all spawn in the same row, so as they increase speed going left there spawning on the asteroids that are already almost off the screen Here's what it looks like.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pKXZyzIpGs&feature=youtu.be

Here's my update code.

```
namespace PixeBlastGame
{
    public class GameUpdate
    {
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        GameTime gameTime;

        Vector2 vPlayer = new Vector2(0, 720 / 2);
        Vector2 vAsteroid;
        Vector2 velocity;
        Random rand = new Random();

        float spawnTimer;
        float spawnRate = 1;
        List<Vector2> Asteroids = new List<Vector2>();


        public GameUpdate()
        {
            vAsteroid.Y = rand.Next(100, 680);
            vAsteroid.X = 1100;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime theTime)
        {
            gameTime = theTime;
            vPlayer.Y += velocity.Y;

            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            spawnTimer += elapsed;



            if (spawnTimer >= spawnRate)
            {
                Asteroids.Add(new Vector2(1000 ,rand.Next(0, 720)));
                spawnTimer = 0;
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                velocity.Y = 5;
            }

            else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                velocity.Y = -5;
            }

            else
            {
                velocity.Y = 0;
            }

            if (vPlayer.Y > 630 )//+ Game1.tPlayer.Height)
                vPlayer.Y = 630;
            if (vPlayer.Y < -10) //+ Game1.tPlayer.Height)
                vPlayer.Y = -10;


        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch theBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch = theBatch;

            foreach (Vector2 asteroid in Asteroids) //Draw each astroid
            {
                DrawAsteroid(asteroid.X, asteroid.Y);
            }

            spriteBatch.Begin();


            spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.tPlayer, vPlayer, Color.White);

            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        public void DrawAsteroid(float x, float y)
        {
            vAsteroid.X -= 5; vAsteroid.Y = y;
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.tAsteroid, vAsteroid, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more code provided to help me, post a comment.

Comment: You need to create a class for your Asteroids, since you need to store the velocity and position of each of your asteroids, get rid of vAsteroid.

Comment: What robert said, I explained that in my answer for your last question. Because each asteroid will have its own velocity.

Comment: The problem is likely to be related to the "new Random".

Comment: it looks like your rand was to small it will be better to do something like `vAsteroid.Y =Asteroid.Height*rand.Next(0,5)` this way you will get your Asteroids in Rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an Asteroid Class

```
public class Asteroid
{
       public Vector2 Velocity;
       public Vector2 Position;
       public Asteroid(Vector2 velocity, vector2 position)
       {
        Velocity = velocity;
        Position = position;
       }
}
```

Now change your list to:

```
List<Asteroid> Asteroids = ...
```

And from now on you can do something like this

```
Asteroids[0].Velocity = Whatever
```

This way you can modify each **instance** of an asteroid

Now take a look at your draw method,

```
public void DrawAsteroid(float x, float y)
        {
            vAsteroid.X -= 5; vAsteroid.Y = y;
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.tAsteroid, vAsteroid, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

Your not even using the x and y values, so whats the point? Now everywhere in your code you MUST remove vASteroid and use the instance in the list!

Change `DrawAsteroid` to this:

```
 public void DrawAsteroid(Asteroid a)
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.tAsteroid, a.Position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }
```

And the call to it..

```
    foreach (Asteroid a in Asteroids) //Draw each astroid
    {
        DrawAsteroid(a);
    }
```

Now we need to do the same thing in update, don't update your positions in `Draw()`

Add this in Update:

```
    foreach (Asteroid a in Asteroids) //Update each astroid
    {
        UpdateAsteroid(a, elapsed);
    }
```

And add the new method...

```
 public void UpdateAsteroid(Asteroid a, float elapsed)
        {
            a.Position += a.Velocity * elapsed;
        }
```

Now, when you spawn an asteroid, you need to make sure you have velocity added!

```
Asteroids.Add(new Asteroid(new Vector2(0,-10), new Vector2(50,50)));
```

That will spawn an Asteroid with a Y *velocity* of -10 and a *position* of 50,50

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't this require me to edit every single asteroid? I want unlimited asteroids coming with the same attributes, spawning then going right on my screen and then gradually getting faster ( Planning on doing later )

Comment: @freemann098 it just mean every time your timer triggert you will create a new Asteroid and add him to your List<Asteroid> like Cyral explained

Comment: @freemann098 Yes it will require you to edit each one, but this is Object Oriented Programming, you will need a SEPERATE velocity for each asteroid,you can now spawn with `Asteroids.Add(new Asteroid(new Vector2(0,5),new Vector2(X,Y)));` for example to spawn an asteroid with 5 Y velocity

Comment: You can always add random numbers with min/max value so you do not have to give unlimited parameters ;)

Comment: Thank you again for answering one of my questions Cyral! :)